# How to change the default version of Python in Debian 7.5?

Tags: debian, python, defaults

I'm using Debian 7.5, and I've installed Python 3.3 and 3.2.  How do I make 3.3 the default for when someone types `python` in the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the version of python that is executed when you type `python` on the command line, and only then, define an alias in your shell initialization file (the one for interactive shells). This is `~/.bashrc` for bash, `~/.zshrc` for zsh, `~/.cshrc` for csh, `~/.config/fish/config.fish` for fish. Use the correct path for Python 3.3 for your installation.

```
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3.3'
```

If you want this to work for all users, you can put it in a system-wide file; however I don't recommend it, because this causes `python` typed on the command line to be a different version from `python` executed from a script or any other place, which is confusing.

In Debian wheezy, `python` in the default search path should be Python 2.7, because there are programs that depend on it (several packages ship Python 2 scripts that have `#!/usr/bin/env python` as their [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line). If you want, you can change the system default for Python 3 to be Python 3.3 instead of the 3.2 that ships with Debian wheezy. To do that, create a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` (you'll need to be root to do this). If you installed Python 3 in directly in `/usr/local`:

```
ln -s python3.3 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

If you installed it somewhere else:

```
ln -s /path/to/python3.3/bin/python3.3 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Scripts that ship with Debian with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3` will keep using 3.2, but scripts that use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` will now use 3.3, and typing `python3` on the command line will invoke 3.3.